# Is there a general way to prevent fraudulent bank accounts from being opened in your name in Canada?

Tags: canada, bank-account, fraud

In the wake of the Desjardins data leak, several of my friends have become aware of fraudulent bank accounts (not credit accounts or lines of credit, to the best of my understanding) being opened in their names using valid data, in Canada.

Disputing these accounts will undoubtedly be a time-consuming and frustrating process over the next few months.

Given that these aren't lines of credit, and therefore won't be affected by a credit freeze, is there any wide-reaching way to prevent bank accounts from being opened, at least in Canada, while this thing blows over?

Answer (score 1):

[Identity theft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_fraud) is constantly reported by media but few people know how to deal with it. Filing a dispute is a wrong way to deal with the situation. The correct way is to report them as identity fraud.

Identity fraud in Canada can be reported to the [CAFC Fraud Reporting System](http://www.antifraudcentre-centreantifraude.ca/reportincident-signalerincident/index-eng.htm) or you can contact them through the toll-free number (operation hour 9:00 am - 4:45 pm).

In the case of identity theft that also involved credit card, one must report to the relevant card centre(Master,Visa, Amex,etc) immediately, which are working 24 hours.

Once reported to the authority, all relevant financial body will be alerted should anyone attempt to open an account using the stolen identity.

(More Clarification)

No, the consumer has no way to pre-emptively stopping the identity thieve to open a services account using theft information and forged documents. A report to the institutional fraud report centre is enough to protect the consumer from most of the legal burden. Nor should the service providers should implement a paranoid pre-emptive process to deal with such issue, it is unnecessary and ineffective.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which asks about *prevention*, not *reaction*.

Comment: @RonJohn Report the fraud usually will alert all the financial provider electronically.

Comment: @mootmoot It will only alert the financial provider *after* the account has been opened.  The OP wants to stop it being opened in the first place.  You have not answered the question.  (The answer may be "it is not possible to do that, so [react like this]" - but you need to say that.)